# How to fit windows form to any screen resolution and how to made my image size fit to form

Tags: c#

I have the following code in which I am trying to display an image and play an MP3 song.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using WMPLib;
using System.Windows;

namespace CreatingInstaller
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
            var size = this.Size;
            var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
            Image img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\Input\\CYMERA_20141109_141742.jpg");
            //this.Width = img.Width;
            //this.Height = screen.Height;
            pb1.Image = img;
            //pb1.Width = img.Width;
            //pb1.Height = screen.Height; 
            pb1.Size = this.Size;
            this.Controls.Add(pb1);

            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

            wplayer.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\\Input\\Nee Sneham - [www.MazaMp3.com].mp3";
            wplayer.controls.play();
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this code Form height is exceeding my screen height and I am unable to see the full image. Image is not fitting in the form.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

write the above line on load event of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Anchors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) for your PictureBox, and maybe [SizeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) also.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best in your case is to avoid to use PictureBox, and set the image in the BackgroundImage of the form and set the form BackgroundImageLayout to Stretch.

In this way you can change the size of form and the image will be stretched automatically.